# Dropbox: Get number of files in a folder

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api, dropbox-sdk

I'm using the following code to get the total number of files present at root level in a folder for Dropbox:

```
public int getFilesCount(@NonNull final String inPath) throws DbxException {
    Log.i(LOGGER, "Getting files count for: " + inPath);
    ListFolderResult result = mClient.files().listFolder(inPath);
    return result.getEntries().size();
}
```

This code works correctly!

But looks like this code first get the list of all files present under the folder and then gets the count. This takes a significant network time. Is there any faster way to just get the total number of files instead of iterating over the directory?

Using Dropbox version 3.0.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a way to retrieve the file count without listing everything and counting unfortunately. We'll consider it a feature request.

Also, note that the `listFolder` interface is paginated, so you aren't guaranteed to get everything in a single call to `listFolder`. You may need to additionally call `listFolderContinue`. You can find more information in the `listFolder` documentation:

https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v3.0.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/files/DbxUserFilesRequests.html#listFolder-java.lang.String-

Comment: please consider this as a feature request.